# Tradução de Valores para Letras em Lua

Tags: lua

Eu estava tentando criar uma função em lua que serve para o usuário poder escrever no terminal, estou usando uma versão modifica do lua então preciso que quando o teclado me mande o código da tecla apertada eu possa pegar esse código e ver:

> 16 = q
>
> 17 = w
>
> 18 = e
>
> 19 = r
>
> 20 = t
>
> 21 = y

Enfim, como posso fazer isso sem escrever 15 mil if cod == 16 then keypressed = q?

Comment: Que tal dois arrays, um com as letras e outro com o número na posição correspondente a cada letra?

Comment: eu nao sei como faz isso mas eu ja terminei meu software